# How to change the line color in a plot using geoplot?

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to use geoplot command to show latitude and longitude and change the line color using a third variable `speed`. Speed is a array of size (120,3). How can I do this considering that I want to represent my data on a map (using geoplot)? The colour and corresponding value can be checked with colourbar.
I am using MATLAB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation of [`geoplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/geoplot.html#d117e477706). Use the name-value pair `'Color','r'` to configure red lines in this case (`r`:red, `k`:black, `b`:blue, `g`:green,... or use a 3x1 RGB array (normalized), see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorspec.html)). You can also use the keyword [`'LineStyle'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linespec.html) to set e.g. dashed lines.

```
c = [1 0 0]; % RGB | [255 0 0]/255
geoplot(...,'Color',c);
```

Comment: I want to specify the colour of line based on a variable. The colour and corresponding value can be checked with colourbar. How can I do the above operation?

Comment: @BhavyaBudhia I edited the answer added sample code to call a ploting function (in general) and set the `'Color'` value through a variable to make the description clear

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One more thing will it also work of c is array of size (120,3)?

Comment: No, you will have to loop through the array. The `'Color'` command the color of all lines that are ploted in this function call. So plot the lines separately using the `hold on` command or you can use the `set` and `get` functions to change the line style afterwards -- but note that you first need to get the handle of each individual line